# Python module loading in child processes on windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, module, multiprocessing

I was under the impression that since the multiprocessing python module cannot fork when spawning new processes on windows, a new process starting, will import the initial module (whichever the parent process is launched with) from scratch. This means for example, that any code not guarded by an `if __name__=='__main__'` clause, will run in the child process. Doing a simple test, this does not always seem to be the case.

Given the following simple package, and a script with the following file structure:

```
test.py
test_package
    │-- __init__.py
    \-- __main__.py
```

and the following contents:

```py
# ------------------------------
# __init__.py
# ------------------------------
print("__init__.py", flush=True)

import multiprocessing


def main():
    print("Hi from the main function!", flush=True)
    p = multiprocessing.Process(
        target=print,
        args=("Hi from the process!",),
        kwargs={'flush': True}
    )
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

```py
# ------------------------------
# __main__.py
# ------------------------------
print("__main__.py", flush=True)

from . import main

if __name__ == __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Hi from the main file!", flush=True)
    main()
```

```py
# ------------------------------
# test.py
# ------------------------------
print("test.py", flush=True)

import test_package

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Hi from the test script!", flush=True)
    test_package.main()
```

Running test.py, as expected, outputs the following:

```
IN > python test.py
OUT> test.py
     __init__.py
     Hi from the test script!
     Hi from the main function!
     test.py
     __init__.py
     Hi from the process!
```

However, when I run the module as a script using `python -m`, I get this:

```
IN > python -m test_package
OUT> __init__.py
     __main__.py
     Hi from the main file!
     Hi from the main function!
     Hi from the process!
```

I would expect `__init__.py` to be printed before the child process output. How are these two use cases different; what am I missing?